# How do I increase the verbosity level of nvidia's drivers in Mythbuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, mythbuntu, logging

nvidia says to do this:

```
% startx -- -verbose 5 -logverbose 5
```

But how can I do it without using startx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this...

From your X desktop (i.e. Ubuntu, Gnome, Xubuntu...) open a console (`Alt-Ctrl-F1`).

Stop the X desktop (`sudo service stop lightdm`) or `gdm` or what ever display manager your X desktion was using.

Run the command `startx -- -verbose 5 -logverbose 5`  note not with `sudo`.  Now a new X desktop will open, and...

Now `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` will have lots more info on what's happening when X starts.

Including the EDID from your monitor or TV, which is what I was looking for...

When done, logout, then restart your X desktop, i.e. (`sudo service start lightdm`) or `gdm` or what ever display manager your X desktion was using. Close your console (`exit`) and rejoin your X destop (`Alt-Ctrl-F7`).